# Drag and drop image C# UWP

Tags: c#, bitmap, drag-and-drop, stream, uwp

My application can take some part of image and drag it and drop it on another instance of same app.

The problem is that when I start dragging my image I always get full image as icon. I have managed to change this by

```
private void DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
    if (currentlyDraggedElement != null)
        e.DragUIOverride.SetContentFromBitmapImage(currentlyDraggedElement);
}
```

But still when this drag exits the first instance of app, it goes back to original image not only part that is dragged. (On the other app when dropped I do get only that one part but dragging seems like I am dragging whole picture)

Why is this happening, how can I fix it?

**Try 1:**

Change the original image in DragStarting by setting img.Source to bitmap created form stream, without setting of content I am still seeing full image

**Try 2:**

```
args.Data.Properties.Thumbnail= RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(iRandomAccessStream);
```

**Try 3:**
Inside of DragStarting I have stream of image I want, from that IRandomAccessStream I can create softwareBitmap

```
var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
args.DragUI.SetContentFromSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
deferral.Complete();
```

**Try 4:**
Creating BitmapImage from current stream

```
args.DragUI.SetContentFromBitmapImage(bitmapImage);
```

Not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that when I start dragging my image I always get full image as icon

If you want to change the showed image when dragging, you need to update the DragUI, so the first and second ways will take no effects. The third way and forth way should work well.

For `SetContentFromSoftwareBitmap`, the following is the completed testing code which can work well you may reference:

```
var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
StorageFile dragshow = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/caffecut.png"));
SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap;
using (IRandomAccessStream currentstream = await dragshow.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(currentstream);
    softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
}
args.DragUI.SetContentFromSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
deferral.Complete();
```

And you can also test the scenario 2 of the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop/cs/Scenario2_DragUICustomization.xaml).  So please check if your `softwareBitmap` is correctly.

For `SetContentFromBitmapImage`, if you create the `BitmapImage` from uri you can directly use the following code:

```
currentlyDraggedElement = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/caffecut.png"));
args.DragUI.SetContentFromBitmapImage(currentlyDraggedElement);
```

But if you set the `IRandomAccessStream` to the `BitmapImage` you need to add `deferral`, since the `SetSource` method is async. Otherwise it may keep the original image. Code as follows:

```
var deferral = args.GetDeferral();
StorageFile dragshow = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/caffecut.png"));
using (IRandomAccessStream currentstream = await dragshow.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    await currentlyDraggedElement.SetSourceAsync(currentstream);
}
args.DragUI.SetContentFromBitmapImage(currentlyDraggedElement);
deferral.Complete();
```

All the above samples are inside [`DragStarting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_DragStarting) event. Since I'm not sure how you get the `IRandomAccessStream`, if you still have issues you may try to save the part image to local folder and try the above code again.

The result:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply!

Yes it works when I drag it inside of application like that, but as soon as cursor leaves application it goes back to full image

Comment: When I moved deferral on the first line of the dragStarting function it started working. 
Thanks!